# How to resolve Matplotlib module not found error when trying to run Mac .app created using pyinstaller

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyinstaller

I have a tkinter-based GUI that allows the user to load a csv file as a dataframe and plot it on a figure canvas. From there I wish to create a Mac app using pyinstaller. I'm using Python 3.9 on a Mac running Big Sur. First, my main script, entitled "Read_CSV_Plot.py':

```
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

from matplotlib.figure import Figure

from tkinter import Tk,filedialog,TOP,Menu

# Main Window
root = Tk()

# File selection
def _open():
    root.filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir= 
"Users/fishbacp/Desktop",title ="Select file",filetypes = (("CSV files","*.csv"), ("all files","*.*")))
    df=pd.read_csv(root.filename)
    fig = plt.figure()
    ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
    df.plot( ax=ax)
    canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=root)
    canvas.draw()
    canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=TOP)

# Quit function
def _quit():
    root.quit()
    root.destroy()

# Main pull-down menu options to open file and exit.
menubar = Menu(root)
filemenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
menubar.add_cascade(label="File", menu=filemenu)
filemenu.add_command(label="Open", command=_open)
filemenu.add_command(label="Exit", command=_quit)
root.config(menu=menubar)

root.mainloop()
```

To create the app, I've attempted to follow the directions for pyinstaller found at https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/spec-files.html#spec-file-options-for-a-mac-os-x-bundle. I understand that I need to add a Bundle option, and I've added some hidden imports:

```
block_cipher = None

a = Analysis(['Read_CSV_Plot.py'],
         pathex=['/Users/fishbacp/Desktop/Python_May_2021'],
         hiddenimports=['pandas','numpy','matplotlib','tkinter',
         'matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg.FigureCanvasTkAgg']

binaries=[],
datas=[],
hookspath=[],
runtime_hooks=[],
excludes=[],
win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
win_private_assemblies=False,
cipher=block_cipher,
noarchive=False)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
         cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
      a.scripts,
      a.binaries,
      a.zipfiles,
      a.datas,
      [],
      name='Read_CSV_Plot',
      debug=False,
      bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
      strip=False,
      upx=True,
      upx_exclude=[],
      runtime_tmpdir=None,
      console=True )

app = BUNDLE(exe,name='Read_CSV_Plot.app',icon=None, bundle_identifier=None)
```

At the terminal I first entered

```
pyi-makespec --onefile —-windowed Read_CSV_Plot.py
```

followed by

```
pyinstaller Read_CSV_Barplot.spec Read_CSV_Plot.py
```

An app appears in the dist folder, which I attempt to run at the terminal. However, doing so yields the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "Read_CSV_Plot.py", line 1, in <module>
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib'
```

I don't understand the reason for this error since I added matplotlib and matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg.FigureCanvasTkAgg as hidden imports.

Answer (score 0):

try this
find   hook-matplotlib.py and change it to

```
from PyInstaller.utils.hooks import exec_statement

mpl_data_dir = exec_statement(
    "import matplotlib; print(matplotlib._get_data_path())")

datas = [
    (mpl_data_dir, "matplotlib/mpl-data"),
]
```

then try again with pyinstaller

Comment: So this results in a new error message:

  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Read_CSV_Plot.py", line 1, in <module>
    from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib.backends'

I tried to rectify this by adding the following to datas (within the brackets):

(mpl_data_dir, "matplotlib.backends/mpl-data"). Running the app at the terminal yielded the same error message. Should I also modify mpl_data_dir? If so, how?

Comment: try not to use spec file.      pyinstaller --onefile --windowed Read_CSV_Plot.py

Comment: Am I correct that if my .spec file is configured correctly, then

`pyinstaller Read_CSV_Barplot.spec Read_CSV_Barplot.py`

should create the app? This is what I tried after adding your suggested code above. During the build process, I noticed that as many lines whizzed by my on the screen, the were some error messages, including

`No module named 'matplotlib' `

`ERROR: Hidden import 'matplotlib.backends' not found `

`Hidden import 'matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg.FigureCanvasTkAgg' not found' `

At the shell in Idle I noted `mpl_data_dir` was an empty string.

Comment: use pyinstaller --onefile --windowed Read_CSV_Plot.py and see if corrects the problem

Comment: No that didn't do it either. Perhaps I need to modify my .spec file and add the directory location of all my packages:

`pathex=['/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages', '/Users/fishbacp/Desktop']`

The build process indicated matplotlib, etc., were found. Running the app yielded a new error message:

`Error loading Python lib '/Users/fishbacp/Desktop/dist/Read_CSV_Plot.app/Contents/MacOS/Python': dlopen: dlopen(/Users/fishbacp/Desktop/dist/Read_CSV_Plot.app/Contents/MacOS/Python, 10): image not found 1 `

No clue what that means.